# NullInjection Error for modular Angular Material Sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

Building a sidenav using angular-material. Wanted to make it more modular so made the sidenav bar and the main toolbar different components. This caused a `NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSidenavContainer!` in our main toolbar test cases even though the MaterialModule/MatSidenavModule is available to the tests.

Tried adding MaterialModule (which contains modules for AngularMaterial) to the imports in the test suite. Also tried adding the other components (NavbarComponent and AppComponent) to the test suite. Also tried adding the modules separately into the file (e.g. `import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav`). Still throwing the error.

Setup 
Angular 8 
Angular Material 8 
Jasmine: 3.4 
Karma: 4.1

To reproduce error:
Clone repository https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/tree/sidenav-test-error
From inside directory

```
git checkout sidenav-test-error
npm install
ng test
```

This is how the sidenav is set up 
app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation">
    <wla-sidenav></wla-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
      <wla-navbar (toggleSidenav)="sidenav.toggle()"></wla-navbar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here goes the test case throwing the error:

```
describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<any>;

  const authServiceStub = {
    user$: of(null),

    async googleSignin() {
      this.user$ = of(TestUtils.getTestUser());
    },

    async signOut() {
      this.user$ = of(null);
    }
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NavbarComponent],
      imports: [
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useValue: authServiceStub
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Github repository
https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/tree/sidenav-test-error

[full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbAiL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add MatSidenavModule to your module

```
imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        MatSidenavModule // this one
      ],
```

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work. MatSideNavModule is already included in MaterialModule

Comment: Which version of Material you currently using ?

Comment: Angular Material 8.0.1

Comment: You should import each of the material modules from their source not just from angular/material

Comment: @YejielWahnich what exactly do you mean? Are you saying 
`import { MatSideNavModule } from @angular/material` is the problem?

Comment: Per the documentation, angular material modules should be imported from its each module allowing tree shakeablility, https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0. you can also see in the example use : https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Comment: @YejielWahnich tried and it's still throwing the error. It seems to be just the main-toolbar component (`wla-navbar`) that's throwing the error.  The actual sidenav bar (`wla-sidenav`) test cases seem to be running fine. I created a special branch for it https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/Weight-Lifting-App/tree/sidenav-test-error